# Exchange web service (EWS) says "Accees denied" when I try to delete calendar event created by me

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to delete a calendar event that I have created a while ago.

**Case 1:**

- I call EWS to create a calendar event using credentials of domain user broom@infusion.com in some room providing email address of the room and then I get ID of the event
- Then I delete the event by calling EWS and providing Id and ChangeKey, and all is fine - meeting is deleted

**Case 2**

- I create event the same way like in Case 1
- I get list of calendar events for this room. Now ID of the event has HexEntryId format. So I use ConvertId method to convert it to EwsLegacyId required by DeleteItem method
- I call DeleteItem method with ID of event provided by ConvertId method, but without ChangeKey (I don't have it)
- DeleteItemResponse says "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

Why can I remove event in Case 1 and I cannot in Case 2? What should I do to delete the event (like in Case 2)?

---

Here are details of request and responses:

```
Case 1:

I call EWS to create a calendar event using credentials of domain user broom@mycompany.com in some room by providing email address of the room – a meeting like this:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\">
      <soap:Body>
            <CreateItem xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\" xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\"  SendMeetingInvitations=\"SendToAllAndSaveCopy\" >
                  <SavedItemFolderId>
                        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id=\"calendar\"/>
                  </SavedItemFolderId>
                  <Items>
                        <t:CalendarItem xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\">
                              <Subject>Instant Meeting</Subject>
                              <Body BodyType=\"Text\">Generated By mycompany Room Booker</Body>
                              <ReminderIsSet>false</ReminderIsSet>
                              <ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>60</ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
                              <Start>2015-10-01T10:26:02.000Z</Start>
                              <End>2015-10-01T10:41:02.000Z</End>
                              <IsAllDayEvent>false</IsAllDayEvent>
                              <LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
                              <RequiredAttendees>
                                    <Attendee>
                                          <Mailbox>
                                                <EmailAddress>brdmlt-mainbrd@mycompany.com</EmailAddress>
                                          </Mailbox>
                                    </Attendee>
                              </RequiredAttendees>
                        </t:CalendarItem>
                  </Items>
            </CreateItem>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope> 

then meeting is accepted and I get ItemID like:

state.ChangeKey: "DwAAABYAAADw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAhxz0"        
state.Id: "AAASAGJyb29tQGluZnVzaW9uLmNvbQBGAAAAAAB5mlhabHe9S4yVHCob9IbcBwDw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAOdnlAADw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAhrdWAAA="                

Then I delete the event by calling EWS and providing Id and ChangeKey:

<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\" xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
      <soap:Header/>
      <soap:Body>
            <m:DeleteItem DeleteType=\"MoveToDeletedItems\" SendMeetingCancellations=\"SendToAllAndSaveCopy\">
                  <m:ItemIds>
                        <t:ItemId Id=\"AAASAGJyb29tQGluZnVzaW9uLmNvbQBGAAAAAAB5mlhabHe9S4yVHCob9IbcBwDw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAOdnlAADw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAhrdWAAA=\" ChangeKey=\"DwAAABYAAADw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAhxz0\"/>
                  </m:ItemIds>
            </m:DeleteItem>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

and all is fine. The event is deleted.

Case 2:

But when I create event the same way and get response like this:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="235" MinorBuildNumber="1" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <m:CreateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:CalendarItem>
              <t:ItemId Id="AAASAGJyb29tQGluZnVzaW9uLmNvbQBGAAAAAAB5mlhabHe9S4yVHCob9IbcBwDw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAOdnlAADw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAhrdYAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAADw3LMNr7pMRqtEFFAbr0MeAAAAhx08" />
            </t:CalendarItem>
          </m:Items>
        </m:CreateItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:CreateItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

and when I list calendar events for this room like below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Header>
            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
            <GetUserAvailabilityRequest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                  <TimeZone xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                        <Bias>300</Bias>
                        <StandardTime>
                              <Bias>0</Bias>
                              <Time>02:0:00</Time>
                              <DayOrder>1</DayOrder>
                              <Month>10</Month>
                              <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
                        </StandardTime>
                        <DaylightTime>
                              <Bias>-60</Bias>
                              <Time>02:00:00</Time>
                              <DayOrder>2</DayOrder>
                              <Month>3</Month>
                              <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
                        </DaylightTime>
                  </TimeZone>
                  <MailboxDataArray>
                        <MailboxData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                              <Email>
                                    <Name/>
                                    <Address>BRDHOU-MAINBRD@mycompany.com</Address>
                                    <RoutingType>SMTP</RoutingType>
                              </Email>
                              <AttendeeType>Room</AttendeeType>
                              <ExcludeConflicts>false</ExcludeConflicts>
                        </MailboxData>
                  </MailboxDataArray>
                  <FreeBusyViewOptions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                        <TimeWindow>
                              <StartTime>2015-10-01T06:34:09</StartTime>
                              <EndTime>2015-10-01T23:59:59</EndTime>
                        </TimeWindow>
                        <MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>60</MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>
                        <RequestedView>Detailed</RequestedView>
                  </FreeBusyViewOptions>
            </GetUserAvailabilityRequest>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

I get response with IDs in some other format (HexEntryId):

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
  <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="235" MinorBuildNumber="1" Version="Exchange2010_SP2" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GetUserAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <FreeBusyResponseArray>
      <FreeBusyResponse>
        <ResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <ResponseCode>NoError</ResponseCode>
        </ResponseMessage>
        <FreeBusyView>
          <FreeBusyViewType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">Detailed</FreeBusyViewType>
          <CalendarEventArray xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <CalendarEvent>
              <StartTime>2015-10-01T06:36:51</StartTime>
              <EndTime>2015-10-01T06:51:51</EndTime>
              <BusyType>Busy</BusyType>
                        <CalendarEventDetails>
                        <ID>00000000B23AEBAC6379B34DBBBA0B525D2BBFD70700C26EC63E0E9E2A49B110258061BF491D000000FDECCA0000C26EC63E0E9E2A49B110258061BF491D0000D9385B8C0000</ID>
                        <Subject>Boardroom Tablet </Subject>
                        <IsMeeting>true</IsMeeting>
                        <IsRecurring>false</IsRecurring>
                        <IsException>false</IsException>
                        <IsReminderSet>false</IsReminderSet>
                        <IsPrivate>false</IsPrivate>
                        </CalendarEventDetails>
            </CalendarEvent>
          </CalendarEventArray>
          <WorkingHours xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <TimeZone>
              <Bias>300</Bias>
              <StandardTime>
                <Bias>0</Bias>
                <Time>02:00:00</Time>
                <DayOrder>1</DayOrder>
                <Month>11</Month>
                <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
              </StandardTime>
              <DaylightTime>
                <Bias>-60</Bias>
                <Time>02:00:00</Time>
                <DayOrder>2</DayOrder>
                <Month>3</Month>
                <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
              </DaylightTime>
            </TimeZone>
            <WorkingPeriodArray>
              <WorkingPeriod>
                <DayOfWeek>Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday</DayOfWeek>
                <StartTimeInMinutes>480</StartTimeInMinutes>
                <EndTimeInMinutes>1140</EndTimeInMinutes>
              </WorkingPeriod>
            </WorkingPeriodArray>
          </WorkingHours>
        </FreeBusyView>
      </FreeBusyResponse>
    </FreeBusyResponseArray>
  </GetUserAvailabilityResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

To be able to call DeleteItem I need this Id in EwsLegacyId format instead of HexEntryId format, so I call ConvertId method:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Header>
            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
            <m:ConvertId DestinationFormat="EwsLegacyId">
                  <m:SourceIds>
                        <t:AlternateId Format="HexEntryId" Id="00000000B23AEBAC6379B34DBBBA0B525D2BBFD70700C26EC63E0E9E2A49B110258061BF491D000000FDECCA0000C26EC63E0E9E2A49B110258061BF491D0000D9385B940000"   Mailbox="BRDNYC-Collab2@mycompany.com" />
                  </m:SourceIds>
            </m:ConvertId>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

and I get 

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header>
            <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="235" MinorBuildNumber="1" Version="Exchange2010_SP2" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
      </s:Header>
      <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <m:ConvertIdResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                  <m:ResponseMessages>
                        <m:ConvertIdResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                              <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                              <m:AlternateId xsi:type="t:AlternateIdType" Format="EwsLegacyId" Id="AAAbAEJSRE5ZQy1Db2xsYWIyQGluZnVzaW9uLmNvbQBGAAAAAACyOuusY3mzTbu6C1JdK7/XBwDCbsY+Dp4qSbEQJYBhv0kdAAAA/ezKAADCbsY+Dp4qSbEQJYBhv0kdAADZOFuUAAA=" Mailbox="BRDNYC-Collab2@mycompany.com" />
                        </m:ConvertIdResponseMessage>
                  </m:ResponseMessages>
            </m:ConvertIdResponse>
      </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

And when I try to call DeleteItem on this Id like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Header/>
      <soap:Body>
            <m:DeleteItem DeleteType="MoveToDeletedItems" SendMeetingCancellations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
                  <m:ItemIds>
                        <t:ItemId Id="AAAbAEJSRE5ZQy1Db2xsYWIyQGluZnVzaW9uLmNvbQBGAAAAAACyOuusY3mzTbu6C1JdK7/XBwDCbsY+Dp4qSbEQJYBhv0kdAAAA/ezKAADCbsY+Dp4qSbEQJYBhv0kdAADZOFuUAAA=" />
                  </m:ItemIds>
            </m:DeleteItem>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

I get 

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="235" MinorBuildNumber="1" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:DeleteItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:DeleteItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <m:MessageText>Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.</m:MessageText>
          <m:ResponseCode>ErrorAccessDenied</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
        </m:DeleteItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:DeleteItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

"Accees denied. Check credentials and try again"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case 1 your deleting the Appointment from your calendar which you have Full Access to. In Case2 it looks like your trying to delete the appointment from the Room Mailbox which you may or may not have Full rights to (the default is read only even if you are the organizer of the appointment its the calendar itself you would need rights to). In the case where you where the organizer of said appointment you would be better to just cancel the appointment in your calendar and send the cancellation through to the Room mailbox and let the auto-accept on the Room mailbox process and perform the delete that way or you would need to assign the mailbox that is trying to do the Delete Full access to the Room mailbox in question.

cheers
Glen

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I need to find the desired meeting in my own (as an organizer) calendar and then delete it. Thanks! However, it is not so easy for me to figure out which meeting to delete. I need to compare location and time of event. I cannot search based on ID.